# synthesized default constructor as deleted

Tags: c++, copy-assignment

I read this in the book:

> The synthesized copy-assignment operator is defined as deleted if a
>   member has a deleted or inaccessible copy-assignment operator, or if
>   the class has a const or reference member.

And why we can not use reference type?

Comment: Because reference *is like const pointer*, cannot be changed (only initialized)

Comment: In your original question, you already showed that you understand the reasoning for `const`: you cannot re-assign a `const` variable. Since that same reasoning also applies to reference variables, I do not really understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're talking about default constructor (and not reassignment or copy constructor).

> const member whose type does not explicitly define a default constructor

It forbids the default constructor, else you will have an uninitialized const value (so useless). (if it was not `const`, the fact that it was uninitialized is not a problem, we may assign it later).

> a reference member that does not have an in-class initializer

It is forbidden also, as reference is similar to a non null const pointer.

```
struct NoDefaultConstructor
{
    // No default constructor can be generated.

    const int i; // which value to set by default ?
    int& r; // reference which object by default?
};

struct InClassInitializerSoDefaultConstruct
{
    // default constructor is generated here.
    const int i = 42;
    int j;
    int& r = j;
};
```

**Edit to answer edited Q**

For assignment, `const` value cannot be changed.
and reference are like non null const pointer.

Note that copy constructor doesn't have this restriction because you may (and have to)
 initialize const` value.

Comment: Sorry. I changed my question.